What do I need to cap this propane line?
I'm removing my old propane stove. I disconnected the hose and this is what's left. The outer diameter of the threads is 3/4 in (as best I can measure with a tape; I don't have calipers).
What do I need to cap it? Do I put a flared cap directly on this, or can I remove the flared part and put a plug into the valve? I see what looks like a tiny seam around the valve (just to the left of the handle in the photo) but my guess is it's not a real seam, and the flared end is the same piece of metal as the valve.


You'd need a special cap called a "Flare Brass Cap Fitting", according to Home Depot, found by web-searching "end cap for gas flare fitting", and matched to the gas flare tip your valve has.
The gas valve appears to have the flare part built into the valve body. The "tiny seam" on the valve body is where the valve is assembled. It does not appear that the flare part can come off the valve. Cap the end of the flare part, don't unscrew the flare part from the valve.
Alternative, if you're sure you'll never want to have propane there again: turn off the propane (if it is still present) to the pipe feeding the valve, then unscrew the valve and cap the end of the pipe directly with a usual pipe cap and gas-compatible tape or pipe sealant.
